# Questions about Hogwarts Paintings

Tags: harry-potter

Can you get cursed into being stuck in a Hogwarts painting?  Do people in the paintings have feelings? Are they secretly trapped in Hogwarts? Are the Hogwarts paintings actually sinister prisons similar to the horcruxes in that they take the "aura" from the witch or wizard and "contain" it in a "tight cage"?

Comment: You've asked a bunch of different questions here. My mouse hovered over the close-as-too-broad button, but honestly I think most (if not all) are answered in the dupe. See also; [Can Hogwarts headmasters only visit one other painting of themselves, and whence cometh it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/can-hogwarts-headmasters-only-visit-one-other-painting-of-themselves-and-whence)